# How do I use an elif statement properly?

Tags: python, pycharm

Please don't judge me.. I've only been working with Python for a month now.
While laying in my bed I thought of making this and created it in a few minutes but I made to many else and if statements and my code just looks so messy, I kept adding things that weren't needed..(For fun :D)
Anyways, here is my code.. If you could tell me how to use the "elif" statements properly that'd be awesome.(I'm still learning python)
***Question***: I've tried using an elif statement multiple times and I keep getting an error. How do I fix this?

```
key = True # Game key, if this is false the program won't work.

print("Please type a password: ") # Asking for users password
Pass = input()
print("Thank you for typing your password, please make sure it's secure by trying again..") # Ask them to confirm their password by re-typing it
Again = input()
if Pass == Again:
    print("Thank you for choosing a working password, please create your character")
    print("Please type your username without numbers")
else:
    print("Something's wrong with your password or username!")

# Has user confirm if his information is correct
User = input()
print("checking..")
if User.isalpha() and key == True:
    print("So your Username is " + User + " and your chosen password is: " + str(Pass))
else:
    print("Either your key is broken or something is wrong..")

if len(User) >= 4: # Checking if the chosen username has 4 or more characters in it
    print("The length of your Username is: ")
    print(str(len(User)))
    print("If this information is correct please type 'true' or 'false'")
else:
    print("Please type a username longer than 4 characters!")

answer = input() # I kinda fucked up because my coding is dirty and unorganized lol..
if answer == str(True):
    print("Thank you, we're setting up your account! :D")
else:
    print("Please re-run the program and fix your information!")
```

Comment: If you post your code with the elifs in and tell us what error you get, someone might be able to help you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your post lacks a clear problem description. In addition it seems like you just dumped all your code. Which is in some cases okay. But in general people prefer a minimal example. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

We can't debug code you haven't posted, and (as is to be expected - you are on a learning exercise here, and there's a lot to think about) your program structure isn't very helpful. For example, when the user enters non-matching passwords you tell them about it, but nevertheless continue to ask them for their username. Don't worry about this, you will soon learn how to fix it.

Since you ask about the `elif`, it is basically a syntax abbreviation for `else if` that avoids going to multiple indentation levels. Suppose you wanted a value of `'1'` or `'2'` to take different actions, and to declare other values invalid. You could write

```
if value == '1':
    #take action appropriate to 1
else:
    if value == '2':
        # take action appropriate to 2
    else:
        raise ValueError("Allowed inputs are '1' or '2'")
```

Note that the different actions are at different indentation levels. The more cases you have to consider, the more levels of indentation you have to introduce. So it's generally felt to be more readable to write

```
if value == '1':
    # Take action appropriate to 1
elif value == '2':
    # Take action appropriate to 2
else:
    raise ValueError("Allowed inputs are '1' or '2'")
```

Now all the actions and decisions are at the same indentation levels. That's pretty much all there is to it. If you leave the `else` case off then you won't take any actions at all, so it's normally used to specify the default action, in this case raising an exception.

PS: If you want to be sure the user has entered two matching passwords before you proceed, look at the `while` loop, which allows you to repeat a set of actions until some condition (in this case the passwords being equal) is true.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I was busy the last two days.. non the less, thank you so much for that explanation as it's helped me a lot. I am currently learning how to properly use the "while" statement as you've suggested! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example if if/elif/else statement in python3:

```
test = 'mytest'

if test == 'not_my_test':
  print('nope')
elif test == 'mytest':
  print('yay')
else:
  print('something else')
```

You can find more information here : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

EDIT:
As a general remark, you should not define variable using capital letters (PEP convention: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?)

Comment: Sorry for the late 2 day response. Thank you for your help and suggestions, they've really helped me. :)

Answer (score 0):

So using Elif

```
if Pass == Again:
    print("Thank you for choosing a working password, please create your character")
    print("Please type your username without numbers")
elif Pass != Again:
    print("Something's wrong with your password or username!")
```

Though what is this error you're getting, we can't really help you without it.

Comment: There's little point repeating the test: if `Pass == Again` isn't true then `Pass != Again` must be, so `if ... else` would be a simpler and more readable way to write that.

Comment: @holdenweb I was just using the first example that popped in my head, you're right it would definitely make more sense to just use `else` for that.

Comment: Sorry for not saying what the problem was.. The problem I was having is that I did not know how to properly use the elif statement and I was just wondering how to fix it and make it more neat. Thanks for your example, it really helped me. :)